# I am getting "expected ';' " error in my class componet code in react 16.3.1

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';

    Class Welcome extends Component{
          render() {
            return <h2>Class component</h2>;
        }
    }
    export default Welcome
```

Above simple for class component is giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

`class` must be in lower letters. it's a reserved language word. I leave some extra enhancements.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Welcome extends Component {
          render() {
            return (<h2>Class component</h2>);
        }
    }

    export default Welcome
```